# How to join two models in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let say i have two models:

```
level:

id
file_number
status


level_process:

process_ptr_id
level_id
```

I want to combine both of my table above to display it in one API using django-rest-framework.. I'm looking for the example on the internet and i cannot find it...by the way i'm using `python 2.7 , django 1.10.5 and djangorestframework 3.6.2`

```
serializer.py

class LevelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = Level
        fields = ('__all__')

class LevelProcessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    level = LevelSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = LevelProcess
        fields = ('__all__')

views.py

class ViewLevelProcessViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    processes = LevelProcess.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LevelProcessSerializer(processes, many=True)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try the following. Create serializer for your `Level` model:

```
class LevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Level
```

Then, inside `LevelProcessSerializer`, include `LevelSerializer` like this:

```
class LevelProcessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    level = LevelSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = LevelProcess
```

Usage in your ModelViewset:

```
class ViewLevelProcessViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LevelProcess.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = LevelProcessSerializer
```

This way, your json will look something like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "level": {
      "id": 3,
      "status": "red"
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @uetoaya this is assuming that `level` inside your `LevelProcess` is a foreign key. If not, let me know

Comment: yes.. `level_id` is a foreign key in `LevelProcess`

Comment: what about queryset in my`views?`

Comment: i try your code and got this error `could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a '.queryset' attribute.`

Comment: @uetoaya see usage in the answer. The error you got is because of something else, I think. Please, paste your code and I will try to help

Comment: i change it like this.. `class ViewLevelProcessViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LevelProcess.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LevelProcessSerializer`

Comment: I'm facing a problem with this. When I try to post data to LevelProcessSerializer's view it does not save level id even though it is sent, Any idea?

Comment: what if I want to have a  filter on `LevelProcessSerializer` serializer??

Answer (score 0):

```
class LevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Level
        fields="__all__"

class LevelProcessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    level = LevelSerializer(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = LevelProcess
    fields= "__all__"
```

Answer (score -3):

#### Don't try to "join" tables. This isn't SQL.

I am assuming your model look like Following,

```
class Level(models.Model):
    .......

class LevelProcess(models.Model):
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level)
```

Now, let's walk for query,

```
l = Level.objects.filter(id=level_id).first()
lp = l.level_process_set.all()
```

This is how we do in Django ORM.

Comment: Doesn't this result in multiple queries for each related LevelProcess? How is that preferable? It is ultimately SQL, you can't just pretend there's not a database engine behind this thing...