# how to write serializer for joined model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i have applied join on two tables with following query,

**VIEWS.PY**

```
class performance(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Leads.objects.select_related('channelId'
        ).values("channelId__channelName").annotate(tcount=Count('channelId'))

    serializer_class = teamwise_lead_performance_serializer
```

but i am unable to catch response using this serializers,

**SERIALIZER.PY**

```
class channel_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Channels
        fields = ['channelName']


class performance_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tcount = serializers.IntegerField()
    channel = channel_serializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        fields = ['tcount', 'channel']
```

actual results:

```
[
    {
        "tcount": 88
    },
    {
        "tcount": 25
    },
    {
        "tcount": 31
    },
    ...
]
```

expected results:

```
[
    {
        "channelName": "abc",
        "tcount": 88
    },
    {
        "channelName": "def",
        "tcount": 25
    },
    {
        "channelName": "ghi",
        "tcount": 31
    },
    ...
]
```

i have tried the following:

[How to join two models in django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197964/how-to-join-two-models-in-django-rest-framework)

**Models.py**

```
class Channels(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    channelName = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "table1"

class Leads(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    channelId = models.ForeignKey(Channels, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='channelId')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "table2"
```

why is it not getting the `channelName` in response?
what am i doing wrong here?
Thank you for your suggestions

### Edit

When I try Mehren's answer, I get the following error:

> KeyError when attempting to get a value for field **channelName** on serializer **performance_serializer**. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the dict instance.Original exception text was: 'channelId'.

Comment: Notice also that each Lead can only have one related Channel. So it does not make sense to set `channel = channel_serializer(many=True, ...)` - there **cannot** be **many** channels here. 
And it is a better idea to make it a CharField, as the provided answers suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the following:

```
class performance_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tcount = serializers.IntegerField()
    channelName = serializers.CharField(source='channelId__channelName')

    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        fields = ['tcount', 'channelName']

class performance(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Leads.objects.select_related('channelId'
        ).values("channelId__channelName").annotate(tcount=Count('channelId'))
    serializer_class = performance_serializer
```

That being said, I would strongly encourage you to follow both [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/) naming conventions.

Here is what your code would look like following said conventions:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    channel_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None)

class Lead(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PerformanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    channel_count = serializers.IntegerField()
    channel_name = serializers.CharField(source='channel__channel_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = ['channel_count', 'channel_name']

class PerformanceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Lead.objects.select_related('channel'
        ).values("channel__channel_name").annotate(channel_count=Count('channel'))
    serializer_class = PerformanceSerializer
```

The main takeaway from this is to **not** change the default name of your `ForeignKey` columns!  It makes working with related models much more confusing, and is possibly the reason for your problem in the first place (although I couldn't prove it).

Comment: You've got a typo in the `Lead` model, in the `channel` field: the related model name should be `Channel` now. It's only one character, and edits have to change at least 6 chars, so I'd have to find something else to nit-pick... Better fix it yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only get the channelName, then it's better to use

```
channelName = serializers.CharField(source='channelId.channelName')
```

Also, please fix your syntax. You are not following the pep8 standards.

**EDIT**

```
class PerformanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tcount = serializers.IntegerField()
    channelName = serializers.CharField(source='channelId.channelName') 

    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        fields = ['tcount', 'channelName']
```

**EDIT**

```
queryset = Leads.objects.select_related('channelId').values("channelId__channelName").annotate(tcount=Count('channelId'))
```

Remove the `.values("channelId__channelName")` part from your view

Comment: if i add ```channelName = serializers.CharField(source='channel.name') ``` ? in performance_serializer, it gives me ```The field 'channel' was declared on serializer performance_serializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.``` ....... i have added models in question

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Basically in case of DRF serializers, the fields that you define manually MUST be present in the Meta.fields as well.

Comment: now i am getting ```Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `channelName` on serializer `performance_serializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'channel'.```

Comment: I've edited the answer accordinv to your model defintions. Hope it helps!

Comment: still geting ```Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `channelName` on serializer `performance_serializer`.The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.Original exception text was: 'channelId'.```