# getting error while join two serializer in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**serializers.py** *-while joining HiringstatusSerializer in DriverEditListSerializer getting error*

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('id', 'name')
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('id', 'name')
class HiringstatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Hiring
        fields = ('driver_id', 'status')
class DriverEditListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = CitySerializer(read_only=True)
    location = LocationSerializer()
    hstatus=HiringstatusSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = ( 'id','employee_id','employer', 'name','uber_name','uber_device_no', 'mobile', 'location', 'city','shift','status', 'aadhar_no','hstatus')
```

**views.py**

```
class DriverViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Driver.objects.filter(is_active=1)
    serializer_class = DriverEditListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Driver.objects.filter(is_active=1, city_id=self.request.GET.get('city_id'))
        return queryset
```

**output error** this is output error while hit url

```
    raise type(exc)(msg)
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `hstatus` on serializer `DriverEditListSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Driver` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Driver' object has no attribute 'hstatus'.
ERROR "GET /fleet/dt/editdrivers/ HTTP/1.1" 500 187937
```

Comment: share your models pls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join two models in django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197964/how-to-join-two-models-in-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

in your nested serializer pass these arguments.

```
class DriverEditListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = CitySerializer(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True)
    location = LocationSerializer(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True)
    hstatus=HiringstatusSerializer(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = ( 'id','employee_id','employer', 'name','uber_name','uber_device_no', 'mobile', 'location', 'city','shift','status', 'aadhar_no','hstatus')
```